# Selective display of views when condition is met

Tags: android

I have an array of String data in file A

```
    String[] obj=new String[{first.getJSONObject(1).getString("flid"),first.getJSONObject(0).getString("flid"),first.getJSONObject(2).getString("flid")};
```

This array holds [100,101,102]
My requirement is I have a file B which holds all the views in it like the below one:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        //ordinary text field
        EditText simple_textfield=new EditText(this);
        simple_textfield.setId(100);
        simple_textfield.setHint("Enter the data");
        simple_textfield.setMaxLines(2);
        simple_textfield.setMinLines(1);
        simple_textfield.setText("EditText view");
        layout.addView(simple_textfield);

        //Integer field
        EditText int_field=new EditText(this);
        int_field.setId(101);
        int_field.setHint("Enter integer");
        layout.addView(int_field);

        //email id field
        EditText email_field=new EditText(this);
        email_field.setId(102);
        email_field.setText("enter email id");
        layout.addView(email_field); 

        //Many more views will come here
```

How can I compare if array data present in file A with the file B ids and display the required fields graphically.

if(id==R.id.x)
{
display the view associated with that id
} 
Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

make a activity which stores data for you like,

```
 public Constant {

 public static String data1="";
.
.
.
 public static String data10="";

}
```

In file B you can store data in Constant:

```
Constant.data1= "put your data here";
```

In file A you can compare here:

```
if("you data".equal(Constant.data1) )
{
  //do something here
}
```

Thats it. Constant will save data temporary it will be erased when application will be stopped. if you want to save them permanently use **sharedPreferences** to save it even after application is closed.

Comment: Could you please explain because I think you are pointing to set and get. How is it ok for generating views?